# Looping over JSON data for MapKit doesn't work

Tags: swift, for-loop, uikit, mapkit

Currently I am coding my first larger iOS app I am looking forward to release in the near future. The challenge I am not able to solve myself is the following:

Given my Webservice `WebServicePins.swift` I am getting data from my own API. It looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Berlin",
    "body": "Capital of Germany",
    "thumb": "*Link to my AWS bucket*",
    "lng_coord": "13.404954",
    "lat_coord": "52.520008",
    "date": "2019-11-10T11:36:31.409361Z",
    "owner": 1,
    "type": "other"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "title": "Munich",
    "body": "Home of the Oktoberfest",
    "thumb": "*Link to my AWS bucket*",
    "lng_coord": "11.576124",
    "lat_coord": "48.137154",
    "date": "2019-11-10T11:36:31.409361Z",
    "owner": 1,
    "type": "other"
  }
]
```

and so on. The web service works fine, and I use the data in  `PinListViewModel.swift`:

```swift
import Foundation

class PinListViewModel: ObservableObject {
   @Published var pins = [PinViewModel]()

    init() {

        WebservicePins().getPins { pins in

            if let pins = pins {
                self.pins = pins.map(PinViewModel.init)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct PinViewModel: Identifiable {

    var pin: Pin

    init(pin: Pin) {
        self.pin = pin
    }

    var id: Int {
        return self.pin.id
    }

    var title: String {
        return self.pin.title
    }

    var body: String {
        return self.pin.body
    }

    var thumb: String {
        return self.pin.thumb
    }

    var lng_coord: String {
        return self.pin.lng_coord
    }

    var lat_coord: String {
        return self.pin.lat_coord
    }

    var date: String {
        return self.pin.date
    }

    var owner: Int {
        return self.pin.owner
    }

    var type: String {
        return self.pin.type
    }

}
```

Using the ObservableObject to display a List in a SwiftUI view à la

```swift
struct ArticlesTabView: View {

    @ObservedObject private var pinListVM = PinListViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(self.pinListVM.articles, id:  \.id) { pin in
                Text(pin.title)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

works as expected, however I am not able to loop over the array as for example in

```swift
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {

        let pinListVM = PinListViewModel()

        let mapView = MKMapView()
        mapView.delegate = context.coordinator

        // Test Annotations
        let testPins = [
            Pin(id: 1, title: "Berlin", body: "Capital of Germany",
                thumb: "", lng_coord: "13.404954", lat_coord: "52.520008", date: "",
                owner: 1, type: "action"),
            Pin(id: 2, title: "München", body: "Home of the Oktoberfest",
            thumb: "", lng_coord: "11.576124", lat_coord: "48.137154", date: "",
            owner: 1, type: "other")
        ]

        for pin in pinListVM.pins {
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.title = pin.title
            annotation.subtitle = pin.body
            annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(pin.lat_coord)!, longitude: Double(pin.lng_coord)!)
            mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        }

        for testPin in testPins {
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.title = testPin.title
            annotation.subtitle = testPin.body
            annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(testPin.lat_coord)!, longitude: Double(testPin.lng_coord)!)
            // annotation.pinTintColor = UIColor.green
            mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        }

        return mapView
    }
```

The `testPins` are being displayed, while the `pins` are not being displayed in the final map. Can you help me find my mistake? Thank you in advance!
PS: I am new to stackoverflow.com, feel free to change my question / tell me how to make it more descriptive or understandable!

Comment: It would help to see your `WebservicePins()`. Does it have a function called `getPins()`? If so, you need to add the the parens to make its use a function call. If it's a variable, then this is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're making a new PinListViewModel in your map view. You should make it an @ObservedObject I think.